# Make Google Map a certain distance (meters) across

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

Has anyone ever come across a way set the google maps zoom level so that the window is a certain distance across?

Comment: Since the window can by any dimension you like, and JavaScript won't necessarily know what those are, I imagine you'd have to do the math yourself.

Comment: I figure I would have to find the distance between the center and the map bound and then fix it so that the zoom level changes that distance so it is within a given tolerance for the desired distance (lets say 200 meters), but I'm stumped as to how I would go about figuring the desired zoom level based on the known map dimensions.

Comment: The distance across a Google Map will depend on: 1. The size of the div containing the map 2. The Latitude  where you want the measurement to be valid 3. The zoom level at which the map is being viewed.  The zoom levels available on the Google Maps API v3 are quantized in factors of 2.  So 2 questions: 1. do you want the map sized to show at least X meters across, or exactly X meters across? (you can only get something approximating "exactly" by changing the size of the map div).  2. Where on the map do you want the size specified, the top, center or bottom?

Comment: Each zoom level of a (full-size) Google Map displays the scale in the bottom-left corner. You could count the pixels and create an associative array in JavaScript with the ratios. Also, it seems to double in size with each zoom level, so if you can figure out one ratio you can use that fact to estimate all the others. At the highest zoom level I count 66 pixels = 50 ft (on my screen, anyway).

Comment: In the end I did almost the exact same thing as @LeJared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Measure witdh of your map in current zoomlevel use `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween()` and `map.getBounds()` (see doku).
2. If measured distance is wider when desired, divide it by two. If it's smaller, multiply by two.
3. Do this until the calculated width gets smaller oder bigger than the target width and count how often you have to multiply or divide.
4. Add / subtact the number you've counted to your current zoomvalue to get your target zoomvalue.

Note: you can not fit your map to an exact width, because you're limited to the fixed zoomlevels, so this is only an approximation.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved a similar thing by creating a circle with the given distance and using that to get the bounds. The width of the map isn't quite the same as the circle as the API adds some padding.

```
//Accuracy in metres
var accuracy = 50; 

/* Create a circle but don't set the 'map' variable as we don't need to see circle on the map */
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                 center: map.getCenter(),
                 radius: accuracy
             });

//Get the new bounds from the circle
var bounds = circle.getBounds();

/* Fit the map to the size of the circle. Will be slightly bigger than the circle as the API adds a little padding */
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```